# $f_n$ is a sequence of bounded real functions converging uniformly to a function $f$ on every finite interval. Is $\limsup f_n(x) = \sup f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm trying to answer whether $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup f_n(x)$ equals the sup of $f(x)$.

Let $(f_n)_n$ be is a sequence of real valued functions defined and bounded on the real numbers such that $(f_n)_n$ converge uniformly to a function $f$ on every finite interval. Is it true that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup f_n(x)  = \sup_n f_n(x)~?$$

I'm not sure how to deal with the sup's in this situation. In fact, I'm not really quite sure what it's asking. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $f_n$ equal $0$ on $[-n, n]$ and equal to $1$ otherwise.